# Bootstrap's td of the table - class with "border-style: none" doesn't remove top border of td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap framework.

I have HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="non-border">First case</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-style:none">Second case</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS code:

```
.non-border { border-style: none; color: red }
```

Why for the first case class "non-border" doesn't remove the top-border of td (for left, right and bottom border it works; CSS works because color changes for red)?

For the second case (style) all borders of td are removed.

What should I do to get working "border-style: none" of td by class?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `!important`. Like so:

```
.non-border { 
    border-style: none !important; 
    color: red;
}
```

All styles are cascaded, but inline styles are given the highest preference. In your case, class `.non-border` is getting lower preference than twitter-bootstrap's predefined styles.